# Does using a Rewrite rule hide the actual URL being accessed?

Tags: javascript, apache, http

Say you have a domain "blah.com" . In your web server, if you set the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://websitetoforwardto.com/foldertoforwardto/$1 [L,QSA]
```

What does a web browser see when it accesses `blah.com/myfolder/myfile.htm` ?
Can the browser see the final destination (`websitetoforwardto.com`) ?

Comment: I think you are looking for ProxyPass via [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)

Comment: I don't think so - if I proxy, then the content will go through my server, so I will be using twice the bandwidth. Did I misunderstand ? I don't wan't to create a proxy, per se, but rather redirect some urls which are not hosted. Some content may still be hosted on my server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since you won't be on the same server. That would essentially be a redirect.

Comment: Can't redirects be seen by the browser ?

Comment: Not directly. All mod_rewrite does it tell apache a new url internally. It does other fancy things but generally that's what it's doing.

Comment: But does that mean that the content of the new url is piped through the server ? I imagine if it is being redirected, and not piped, the browser would somehow "know" that its going somewhere else ?